# Static constructor BEFORE reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

If I load an assembly, and get a static readonly field of a given type, and I expect that field to be initialized on static constructor, and I call GetValue on that field, will it have a value (since I'm accessing a field on a type, so it needs to be typeinitialized)?

(No, I'm not planning on calling the static constructor from reflection...)

Comment: Are you not able to call GetValue and get the value back?

Comment: Seems like this would be pretty easy to test...

Comment: Come on TDaver - you know enough to verify this on your own!

Comment: yeah I figured out I overcomplicated my test case :) Sorry for wasting your time :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like a yes to me.

```
// In SomeAssembly.dll
public class TestClass
{
    public static readonly int Field;

    static TestClass()
    {
        Field = 5;
    }
}

// In its own assembly
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public;

        Assembly someAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"Path\To\SomeAssembly.dll");

        object field = someAssembly.GetType("TestClass")
                                   .GetField("Field", bindingFlags)
                                   .GetValue(null);

        Console.WriteLine(field);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
5
```

Comment: He states 'Load an assembly', does this work even if the assembly with the static field is loaded at runtime (which i presume he means)? cant see why it wouldnt but im far too lazy to try it myself..

Comment: @Richard: I actually did try it, and yes, it works in that case too... I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks again for testing it! My code kept throwing exceptions and it took me a while that it had nothing to do with the static field :)